# put a string with html/Javascript into selenium webdriver

Tags: java, javascript, selenium-webdriver

I have a html document in memory as a string. It contains a `<script>` tag with a little script that manipulates the dom. I now want to load that html page into selenium webdriver and get back the page after the script manipulates it. Since I have the html already in memory, I don't like the idea much of writing the html into a file and load it as file with `driver.get("file://path/to/file")`. So the question is, if there is a possibility to achieve what I want.

IF webdriver can't do it, maybe there is a possibility other than that?

Here comes an example:

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function fill(){
    var i = "secret"
    document.forms[0].elements[1].value=i
}
</script>
</head><body onload="fill()">
<form method="POST"><input type="hidden" name="he1" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="he2" value="">
</form></body></html>
```

Obviously, I want the webdriver to perform the dom manipulation and change the form according to the script.

**Note** this is just an example. The actual script I need to run does much more complicated things.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

this code can load any html string which include js and css.

```
html_bs64 = base64.b64encode(innerHtml.encode('utf-8')).decode()
driver.get("data:text/html;base64," + html_bs64)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I can't test this at the moment. It looks similar to the solution that jolancornevin suggested in his answer 2 years ago. Anyone reading this and feels inclined to test it out, please report if this actually executes the Javascript as intended.

Comment: Hey @luksch I just tested and it indeed works, and better than the previous answer.

Answer (score 46):

If you don't want to create a file or load a URL before being able to replace the content of the page, you can always leverage the [Data URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) feature, which supports HTML, CSS and JavaScript:

```
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
html_content = """
<html>
     <head></head>
     <body>
         <div>
             Hello World =)
         </div>
     </body>
</html>
"""

driver.get("data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + html_content)
```

Comment: So cool! After >4 years, finally comes someone with an answer that is doing the trick! Thanks :)

Comment: Javascript won't run.

Comment: I did not verify that this works. Could you elaborate Fan Jin?

Comment: This is very smart! And answering the other questions here, it fails because if you have any special characters like a ' it will break. The base64'd version from @moyang fixes this.

Answer (score 21):

You could load an empty page eg:

```
<html></html>
```

And then set it's innerHTML

```
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("file://empty-page.html");
String innerHtml = "<head>...</head><body onload="...">...</body>";
driver.executeScript("document.innerHTML = " + innerHtml);
```

Then fire the load event on the body

```
driver.executeScript("$(document.body).trigger('load');");
```

Then get the resultant HTML

```
String result = driver.executeScript("document.body.innerHTML;");
```

Comment: awesome... great idea. I will try it asap.

Comment: This isn't guaranteed to work with IE. IE gets very emotional with local HTML files and throws it's toys out of the pram (because of it's security zones, there is a specific zone for local sites)

Comment: IE has one purpose... to download chrome ;)

Comment: It did not work - I now write the file and read it again. That works at least

Comment: All modern browsers support the about:blank URI schema.  Just call `driver.get('about:blank');` to load an empty HTML page.

Answer (score 6):

Using Java Selenium 2.4.2 I use the following to replace inner html of an existing element.  I use the Apache StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript to escape the HTML because this is a JavaScript replace of the inner html.

```java
    public void replaceHTML(By by, String html) {
      WebElement e = driver.findElement(by);
      ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].innerHTML='" + StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript(html) + "'", e);
    }
```

Example html String I passed in.

```html
<button type="button" onclick="alert('Hello world!')">Click Me!</button>
```

Notes:

- I couldn't get "Lance Java's" approach to work because of invalid
  escaped characters.  Adding a single quote after the equal sign fixed
  this problem.
- I tested "Kenneth Baltrinic's" suggestion of using
  driver.get('about:blank'); but I wasn't able to write to the screen
  interacting with the base document. In java I had to use double
  quotes driver.get("about:blank"). I tested this with Chrome.

Comment: I will test this. Thanks for the late response.

Answer (score 3):

Just a small update: escape**Ecma**Scrip() replaces escapeJavaScript() in 2015.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{ 
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxTree/");
    replaceHTML(By.xpath("//*/span[text()='Supported browsers:']"), "<button type=\"button\"  onclick=\"alert('Hello World!!')\">Click Me!</button>");
}

 private static void replaceHTML(By by, String html) {
      WebElement e = driver.findElement(by);
     ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].innerHTML='" + StringEscapeUtils.escapeEcmaScript(html) + "'", e);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could fire up [jetty embedded](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/embedding-jetty.html). The jetty instance could then serve in memory html strings as web pages via a Servlet / Handler.

Comment: there is no kill like overkill :)