# Python Selenium On Local HTML String

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to run Selenium on a local HTML string but can't seem to find any documentation on how to do so. I retrieve HTML source from an e-mail API, so Selenium won't be able to parse it directly. Is there anyway to alter the following so that it would read the HTML string below:

Python Code for remote access:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("q")
```

Local HTML Code:

```
s = "<body>
        <p>This is a test</p>
        <p class="q">This is a second test</p>
     </body>"
```

Comment: should that not be .find_element_by_class_name ? is that the underlying problem or is this just a typo

Comment: What is the expected output or why is it now working?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, I can imagine 2 ways to do this:

1. Save HTML code as file, and load it as url `file:///file/location`. The problem with that is that location of file and how file is loaded by a browser may differ for various OSs / browsers. But implementation is very simple on the other hand.
2. Another option is to inject your code onto some page, and then work with it as a regular dynamic HTML. I think this is more reliable, but also more work. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22538457/put-a-string-with-html-javascript-into-selenium-webdriver) has a good example.

Comment: I think I'll go with the injection. Thanks.

Comment: I found below works for me                                                                          location = "file:///Users/your_username/github/login_automation/landing.html"
driver.get(location)
print (driver.page_source)

Answer (score 23):

If you don't want to create a file or load a URL before being able to replace the content of the page, you can always leverage the [Data URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) feature, which supports HTML, CSS and JavaScript:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
html_content = """
<html>
     <head></head>
     <body>
         <div>
             Hello World =)
         </div>
     </body>
</html>
"""

driver.get("data:text/html;charset=utf-8,{html_content}".format(html_content=html_content))
```

Comment: This is limited to 65535 characters.

Comment: Yes and no, it actually depends on the browser that you are using. CF https://stackoverflow.com/a/41755526/5061294.

Answer (score 6):

Here was my solution for doing basic generated tests without having to make lots of temporary local files.

```
import json
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()  # or your browser of choice

html = '''<div>Some HTML</div>'''
driver.execute_script("document.write('{}')".format(json.dumps(html)))
# your tests
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, but seems to do the trick for me.

Comment: Sad, but throws a JavascriptException: SecurityError: The operation is insecure.

Comment: `re.escape` is more appropriate than `json.dumps` to turn the special characters of a string into escaped characters. The latter won't escape single quotes, for example, and this breaks the string within `document.write()`

Answer (score -1):

If I am reading correctly you are simply trying to get text from an element.  If that is the case then the following bit should fit your needs:

```
    elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("q").text
    print elem
```

Assuming "q" is the element you need.

Comment: I'm trying to parse a local string. So rather that feed a url to "driver.get", I would want to pass the html string to it.