# Loading dynamic url using Selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, url, selenium-webdriver

I have a html string (can not write it to file) in memory, I want to render the html string in Selenium remote webdriver and take the screenshot. Following is the code i used

```
RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:9515"), capabilities);
driver.get("about:blank");
((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
.executeScript("arguments[0].innerHTML='" + StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml3(_html) + "'");
```

The problem with this approach is, it is breaking the java script execution because of the new line character or some other characters and getting the below error

```
{"errorMessage":"Unexpected EOF","request":{"headers":{"Accept-Encoding":"gzip,deflate","Connection":
```

I got the log error message so i have pasted only certain portion of it.

I have looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22538457/put-a-string-with-html-javascript-into-selenium-webdriver) in SO but it did not help me much.

Can you please help me to solve this? My question is i want to load the html string in selenium driver and take the screenshot.

Comment: It seems like saving the html to a file and then opening the file is simplest.

Comment: i am using Apache strom, and can not save the string to file :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `_html` is your html string, it should be along the lines of:

```
driver.executeScript('document.body.innerHTML = arguments[0]', _html)
```

You shouldn't need to escape quotes or newlines.

Answer (score 1):

To open in the dynamic *URL* in the same *TAB* you can use:

```
driver.get("about:blank");
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.location.replace(" + StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml3(_html) + ");");
```

To open in the dynamic *URL* in a new *TAB* you can use:

```
driver.get("about:blank");
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open('" + StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml3(_html) +"');");
```