# Display name of cucumber step while executing test

Tags: java, selenium, automation, cucumber, gherkin

I'm trying to display the step that is currently running within the browser. So imaging the following are my steps in the .feature file

```
Given I navigate to "website"
When I click on an option
Then something happens
```

So if the first step is running I would like to see that step displayed somewhere on the browser so it is visible for my manager to see what is happening during the test. Does anyone have a solution for this? Or know of a plugin that could solve this problem I'm facing?

Comment: I can easily implement that for you :)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please update your question with your code.

Comment: @UnknownBeast can you share a link so that I can implement this into my framework?

Comment: @Dhamo Thank you for the warm welcome! 

I currently don't have any code for this. I actually am trying to get information about if there is something like this that exists and how to implement it into my project.

Comment: You can try inject html code using selenium, and display the step. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22538457/put-a-string-with-html-javascript-into-selenium-webdriver

Comment: I already have a utility to display steps but it will lead to the repetitive task. You can view from below https://www.github.com/frostyaxe/frostylight what I am planning to do is I will use cucumber listener and display those steps for you in the browser and what all configuration you need is just adding the plugin in runner file.

Comment: You can view the StepDescriptor code but if you something as discussed above then I could complete that in a day 